# How to configure __main__.py, __init__.py, and setup.py for a basic package setup?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

### Background:

I have a directory structure like so:

```
Package/
    setup.py
    src/
        __init__.py
        __main__.py 
        code.py
```

I want to be able to run the code in a lot of different ways.

1. `pip install Package` and then `python` and then `from Package import *`
2. `python -m Package` which should do the thing in `__main__.py`
3. `python __main__.py` which should also do the thing in `__main__.py` but this time, we assume you've downloaded source rather than `pip installing`.

Now I've gotten the first two to work, but with a messy setup:

**setup.py:**

```
setup(
    name='Package',
    packages=['Package'],
    package_dir={'Package': 'src'},
    ...
    entry_points={ 'console_scripts': ['Package = src.__main__:main' ] }
```

**__init__.py:**

```
from Package.code import .......
```

**__main__.py:**

```
from . import .......
```

What would make more sense to me would be in both cases to write

```
from code import ........
```

but that gives me import errors.

## Question:

Is the way I have it really the only way?

And most importantly, how do I support the third use case? Right now, `python __main__.py` throws

```
File "__main__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from . import code
ImportError: cannot import name 'class defined in code.py'
```

### Notes:

I have read

- https://chriswarrick.com/blog/2014/09/15/python-apps-the-right-way-entry_points-and-scripts/
- http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html
- The many questions here that look like this one but don't answer my question above.

Comment: `from code import` is implicit relative import which is not recommended (and doesn't work in Python 3). Either use absolute import or explicit relative import.

Comment: @phd could you elaborate a little bit as to what each of those are?

Comment: Absolute import means to use full path: `from Package.somemodule.submodule import` even inside Package or somemodule. Relative import is to import from neighbours without using full path. `from code import` is implicit rel. import because it looks like absolute but really is relative. Relative import was the default mode in Python 2 but its implicit mode is now forbidden in Python 3 (default is now abs. import). Explicit relative import is `from .code import` — see the dot in `.code`? It means "import from the current module".

Comment: Got it, so now we should always do `from Package.somemodule.submodule import` ?

Comment: This is what PEP8 recommends (though officialy PEP8 is only for stdlib).

Comment: You should not use `python Package/__main__.py` (your option 3). You should use `python Package/` instead. It will run the `Package/__main__.py` file automatically (the `python` command accepts *directories*).

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You have almost everything you need (even a bit more)! I'd go with the following setup:

**code.py**:

```
foo = 1
```

**__init__.py:**

```
from .code import foo
```

Doing a relative import here because `__init__.py` will be used when importing the whole package. Note that we explicitly mark the import as relative by using the `.`-syntax because this is required for Python 3 (and in Python 2 if you did `from __future__ import absolute_import`).

**__main__.py:**

```
from Package import foo

print('foo = ', foo)
```

This is the package's main script and so we use an absolute `import` statement. By doing so we assume that the package has been installed (or at least has been put on the path); and that is the way packages should be dealt with! You might think that this conflicts with your third use case but actually there is no reason *not* to `pip install` when dealing with a package. And it really isn't a big deal (especially when using a [`virtualenv`](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/))!

If your concern is to tinker with the source files and readily observe the changes by running the `__main__.py` file then you can simply install the package using the `-e` ("editable") switch: `pip install -e .` (assuming you are in directory `Package`). With your current directory structure, however, this won't work because the `-e` switch will place an `egg-link` to the directory containing the `setup.py` file; this directory does not contain a package named `Package` but `src` instead (I have [a question about that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45139571/3767239)).

Instead, if you follow the convention to name the root directory of a package's source after the package itself (that is `Package` for your example) then installing with `-e` is not a problem: Python *does find* the required package `Package` in the corresponding directory:

```
$ tree Package/
Package/
├── setup.py
└── Package   <-- Renamed "src" to "Package" because that's the package's name.
    ├── code.py
    ├── __init__.py
    └── __main__.py
```

This also lets you omit the extra definition of `package_dir={'Package': 'src'}` in `setup.py`.

**A note about `setup.py`**: For the three use cases which you've specified there is no need to define an entry point. That is you can skip the line `entry_points={ 'console_scripts': ['Package = src.__main__:main' ] }`. By shipping a `__main__.py` module `python -m Package` will readily execute the code in this module. You can also add an extra if-clause:

```
def main():
    print('foo = ', foo)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The entry point on the other hand lets you directly execute the code in `__main__.main` from the CLI; that is running `$ Package` will execute the corresponding code.

## Recap

The bottom line is that I'd always use `pip install` when dealing with packages. And why not, especially if you've already created a `setup.py` file? If changes to the package are to be applied "in real-time" then you can install with the `-e` switch (this might require a renaming of the `src` folder, see above). So your third use case would read as "Download the source and `pip install (-e) Package` (within a virtualenv); then you can run `python __main__.py`".

---

## Edit

### Run `__main__.py` without `pip install`

If you don't want to install the package via pip but still be able to run the `__main__.py` script, I'd still go with the above setup. Then we need to make sure that the `from Package import ...` statement(s) are still succeeding and this can be achieved by extending the import path (note that the this requires the `src` directory to be renamed to the package's name!).

#### Modify `PYTHONPATH`

For Linux bash you can set the Pythonpath as follows:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/Package
```

Or if you're in the same directory as `__main__.py`:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:`cd ..; pwd`
```

Of course there are different ways for different operating systems.

#### Extend the path in `__main__.py`

You (or rather your colleague) could add the following lines to the top of the script (before the `from Package import ...` statements):

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/Package')
```

#### Extend the path in `sitecustomize.py`

You can place a module named [`sitecustomize.py`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html) in the `lib/python3.5/site-packages/` directory of your Python installation which contains the following lines:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/Package')
```

#### Create a separate, top-level `main.py` script

So you'd have the following layout:

```
$ tree Package/
Package/
├── main.py   <-- Add this file.
├── setup.py
└── src
    ├── code.py
    ├── __init__.py
    └── __main__.py
```

where `main.py` contains

```
import src.__main__
```

Now `__main__.py` is treated as a part of the `src` package and the relative import will work.
Instead of running `python src/__main__.py` you would run `python main.py` now.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because it's the most complete and thorough. Thanks for your answer a_guest! I'm only bummed there's no easy way to clone the repo (instead of pip installing) and running main.py directly -- one of my colleagues was hoping to use the code that way... I might put a try-except block at the top of the file for importing, but that feels icky...

Comment: @AlexLenail Now I understand a bit better what you need the third use case for. I made an edit to my answer which contains a few suggestions on how to run `__main__.py` without having done `pip install` beforehand. They are based on extending the import path with the directory in which the source folder is located (they require the `src` directory to be renamed to the package's name). No changes to the actual code are required though. On the other hand I'd expect the repo to contain the `setup.py` file and you can `pip install` from that file. So it really isn't that difficult.

Comment: Thanks a_guest! I appreciate your taking the time to help a ton!

Comment: Nice answer. Note that you need not and should not modify the Python path to run the `Package/__main__.py` file from the file system. Simply type `python Package/` instead of `python Package/__main__.py` and this will work (the `python` command accepts *directories*).

Comment: Also about Python path manipulations, note that you can also create a [path configuration file](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html) in one of the four `sys.prefix`, `sys.exec_prefix`, `sys.prefix`/lib/site-packages, `sys.exec_prefix`/lib/site-packages directories of your Python environment. It is a file with a `.pth` extension whose contents are additional paths (one per line) appended to `sys.path` by the [`site`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html) module which is automatically imported at `python` startup unless the `-S` option is used.

Comment: This is really helpful. How would you structure adding tests to this this package structure. Should tests be using relative imports for tested elements as well?

Comment: @Konrad There are different approaches, either including the tests with the actual package (inside `src`) or, more commonly, having a separate test directory (next to `src`). In any case I would use only absolute imports inside tests as it makes it clear what is being tested and independent of the test's location. There exist many opinions on how to structure the test directory, but loosely it should follow the package's structure. You can check out popular projects such as [requests](https://github.com/psf/requests) or [attrs](https://github.com/python-attrs/attrs) to explore how they did it.

Answer (score 3):

`from code import .........` fails because there is no Python package installed on your system named `code`. There is a Python *module* on your system named `code`, but in your import statement you don't specify the package that your `code` module can be found in.

The purpose of the `__init__.py` file that you have in `src/` tells Python that the `src/` directory should be treated a Python package, with its contents as the modules within the package. Since `code.py` is located in `src/` along with your `__init__.py` file, your `code` module is located in your `src` package.

Now that you know which package your `code` module can be found in, you can import stuff from it with:

```
from src.code import .........
```

Also, as a side note: The `__init__.py` does its job just by being present in your `src/` directory, so it doesn't even need to contain any code. For that reason it's generally a good idea to leave the `__init__.py` file blank.

Comment: Hi @MatTheWhale! Thanks for answering here. Unfortunately, I'm not sure you've answered my question about `__main__.py`, specifically, how to support the third use case, which probably requires something to replace `from . import ....`. Also, leaving `__init__.py` blank for this package doesn't work when other folks install the package.

Comment: @MatTheWhale I cannot follow your argumentation; `code` is located in the _directory_ `src` but the package's name is `Package`, so I don't see how `from src.code import ...` would help. Also "the purpose" of an `__init__.py` is much different in Python 2 than in Python 3, and I don't agree that "it's generally a good idea to leave the `__init__.py` file blank" - there are many cases where `__init__.py` is actively used; just imagine making contents available at the package level.

Answer (score 1):

I often use this setup because it works better with `python setup.py develop`

```
Package_root/
    setup.py
    src/
        Package/
            __init__.py
            __main__.py 
            code.py
```

It's probably not (yet) the detailed answer you're expecting but I think it's worth trying for the three use cases.

```
setup( ...
    package_dir = {'': 'src'},
    entry_points = {'console_scripts': ['Package = Package.__main__:main'],},
    packages = find_packages(exclude=["Package.egg_info",]),
...)
```

Comment: what does package_dir = {'': 'src'} do?

Comment: @ikamen I think I found this syntax in [this doc page](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#including-data-files)