# Install package with separate source directory in editable mode

Tags: python, pip, package, setuptools, distutils

## Situation

This is the structure of an example package:

```
$ tree Foo/
Foo/
├── setup.py
└── src
    ├── bar.py
    └── __init__.py
```

The package's name shall be `foo` however the package's source files are placed in the `src` folder.

The files' contents are:

**setup.py:**

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='foo',
    version='1',
    packages=['foo'],
    package_dir={'foo': 'src'}
)
```

**__init__.py:**

```
from .bar import bar

print(bar)
```

**bar.py:**

```
bar = 1
```

## Problem

When doing `pip install Foo` everything is fine and I can use the package as I'd expect:

```
>>> import foo
1
```

However when I install the package in editable mode (`pip install -e Foo`) it doesn't work:

```
>>> import foo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'foo'
```

Instead I can import `src` now:

```
>>> import src
1
```

Installing with the `-e` switch created a `site-packages/foo.egg-link` file with the following content:

```
<path-to>/Foo
.
```

A corresponding `foo.egg-info` directory has been created in `Foo`:

```
$ tree Foo/foo.egg-info/
Foo/foo.egg-info/
├── dependency_links.txt
├── PKG-INFO
├── SOURCES.txt
└── top_level.txt
```

The `SOURCES.txt` file contains:

```
$ cat Foo/foo.egg-info/PKG-INFO
foo.egg-info/PKG-INFO
foo.egg-info/SOURCES.txt
foo.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
foo.egg-info/top_level.txt
src/__init__.py
src/bar.py
```

and the `top_level.txt`:

```
$ cat Foo/foo.egg-info/top_level.txt 
foo
```

So during the import Python seems to ignore the information which is presented in `Foo/foo.egg-info/` but instead just scans `Foo/` for a package called `foo` (which is not found).

## Question

How can I prepare a package which uses a separate source folder (whose name is different from the package name) so that I can install it in editable mode and still use it as it was installed normally (that is `import <package-name>` should work in any case for example).

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is the package directory named `src` in the first place?

Comment: @Grimmy Admittedly I normally _do follow_ the convention to name the source root directory after the package (so `foo` in this example) which technically resolves the above mentioned problem. However I discovered that `distutils` / `setuptools` support custom names for the source directory and so I wondered how well this plays together with installing in editable mode. Thus this question is more of "curious relevance".

Answer (score 0):

I believe that in the src folder there should be a foo folder that contains **init**.py and bar.py that way the package name will be foo and you can import the foo package. Not sure why it behaves differently in editable mode though.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem with a `src`-style layout as described [here](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html#src-layout).

[Here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/local-project-installs/) it is noted what `pip` editable install does:

> This is functionally the same as setuptools’ develop mode, and that’s precisely the mechanism used for setuptools-based projects.

So to answer the question, setting the root of the package (an empty string) with `package_dir={'': 'src', ....}` is what worked for me. Then, `src` has been added to the path in the `....egg-link` file.