# Given my file structure, what commands should I use to import the following modules?

Tags: python

I'm struggling to consistently import modules that I have written in python, using the Spyder IDE set to the directory of my top-level python script. The following is my file structure, based on [this](https://chrisyeh96.github.io/2017/08/08/definitive-guide-python-imports.html#summary--key-points) guide.

```
root_folder/
    submodules
        moduleA/
            data/ # contains input Excel files
            output/ # contains output files
            code1.py
        moduleB/
            data/
            output
            code2.py
    main.py
    code3.py
```

From `main.py`, I'm trying to import `code1.py` with `from .submodules.moduleA import code1`, but I get this error: `"No module named '__main__.submodules'; '__main__' is not a package"`

I'm also trying to import `code3.py` from `main.py`, for which I've tried to use `from . import code3`, but I get a similar error as before: `cannot import name 'code3' from '__main__' (unknown location)`

Given my file structure, what commands do I use to have relative imports of my modules?

Comment: Relative imports require an installed package ; you need a setup.py, and maybe an `__init__.py`. For instance here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44977227/how-to-configure-main-py-init-py-and-setup-py-for-a-basic-package

Comment: what Python version are you using?

Comment: Now python 3.7.7

Comment: you don't need to use relative import here.  Just `from submodules.moduleA import code1` and `import code3`. There are slight differences in Python2 (you would need `__init__.py` files here and there), but with Python3 you're good

Comment: Am I misunderstanding what "relative imports" are? What case do you have to use relative imports for?

Comment: Relative imports = those starting with dots, like `import .code3`. Here you have a clear point of entrance, which is main. Even in lower level directories, the folder structure is known. However, if you're writing a package that will be imported from arbitrary place, to refer to internal submodules of your package you might want to use those dots.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks! When you're writing a package, can you use relative imports to refer to scripts above a current script? I.e. call `code3.py` from `code1.py`?

Answer (score 0):

One of the challenging concepts of python is that the top level scripts you run are not modules* and are not in a package. You'll notice for instance that the top level script is always `__name__ == __main__`. This is closely patterned on operating system programs where executables are in the `PATH` but the libraries they load are in some system defined `LIB` path. The idea is that python modules and packages are shared by all scripts regardless of where they are.

In a nod to people's aversion to actually bundling and installing python packages, python adds the script's directory to its module path. This makes .py files that are peer to the script importable modules and any subdirectories potentially importable packages. This is risky business as .py files that happen to be in the same directory can shadow like-named modules you want to import.

Notice that .py files that are peer to main.py are not in packages. `code3.py` is not in the `submodules` package and it can't use relative imports either.

When you run `main.py` it can

```
import submodules.moduleA.code1
```

But it can't do any relative imports. Interestingly, `main.py` can import itself

```
import main
```

and there would be a second copy of main running, with a different namespace. And its name would be `__name__ == "main"`.

(*) that was a bit strong. Top level scripts become a module called `"__main__"`.

Comment: I don't quite fully understand your (paragraph 1), which feels very in the weeds w/ PATH and LIB and like something I don't actually need to fully understand, and your (paragraph 3 and on). When you say "peer to main.py", are you referring to any python file that is in the same directory as main.py?

Comment: Could you add on when "relative imports" should be used? Why can't main.py do any relative imports?

Comment: Relative import only works within a package and `main.py` isn't in a package. Generally, a package is a directory somewhere in the python path. In your example, `submodules` became a package because its a peer directory to main.py that you ran as a script. Its not generally available to other scripts in other directories. Since `moduleA` and `moduleB` are subpackages, relative imports work between them.`code3.py` is not in the package so its not available for relative imports.

Comment: Ah, that makes complete sense. Thank you!